# How to capture index Location of BOOL Array

Tags: c#, arrays

I have a Bool Array  and I need to capture all index numbers where the elements are true.  how can This be done?

this is what I have so far

```
bool[] keepPageArray;
StringBuilder PageOneIndexLocation = new StringBuilder(50000);

//Assign the bool array

 keepPageArray = new bool[document.Pages.Count];
// Processing is done here to give each index location value of true or false 
//below is where I am having difficulty
  for (int i = 0; i <= keepPageArray.Length - 1; i++) 

            {
                if (keepPageArray[i].ToString() == "True")
                {
                    PageOneIndexLocation.Append(i); 
                    PageOneIndexLocation.Append(';');
                }
```

result of pageOneIndexLocation is something like this  when I run the program

- PageOneIndexLocation    {0;0;1;0;1;2;0;1;2;3;0;1;2;3}   System.Text.StringBuilder

Where is what I am expecting is 
 PageOneIndexLocation {0;1;2;4;6;7;8;10;} the numbers here represent all locations of my bool array that are true.

Please feel free to tell me where I am going wrong.

Comment: Can you elaborate on your comment

Answer (score 2):

Replace

```
 if (keepPageArray[i].ToString() == "True")
```

with

```
if (keepPageArray[i])
```

Comment: I did that  but the result still shows  something like this     PageOneIndexLocation {0;0;1;0;1;2;0;1;2} System.Text.StringBuilder

Comment: @user2314840 What does your use of the stringbuilder look like?

Comment: Thank you all I got it to work.  It was running under another loop Which I didn't see.  That is why it was throwing up the count on my string builder.  Thank you all

Answer (score 1):

You could do it using a `Lambda query` and `String.Join` method without a loop as below.

```
//Example of your bool array
bool[] keepPageArray = new bool[] {true, true, true, false, true, false, true,
                                       true, true, false,true};
//Get the index of true values  
var trues = keepPageArray.Select((b, index) => new {Index = index, Val =b})
                         .Where(b=> b.Val)
                         .Select(b=> b.Index)
                         .ToList();

//String concatenation using Join method                             
string myString = string.Join(";", trues);

//Print results 
Console.WriteLine(myString);
//Results: 0;1;2;4;6;7;8;10
```